# License Agreement finish button is disabled in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

The license Agreement finish button is disabled in Android Studio.I cannot accept the License

[image: Agreement in Android Studio because I think my finish button is disabled.Please help anyone]

How can I accept the license?

Comment: Did you try scrolling to the end?  A lot of apps require that so they can claim you read it.

Comment: Scroll to the bottom it will fix.

Comment: Scrolling to the end is necessary but not enough.  See answer below.

Answer (score 15):

You should click on the *accept* button for each of the three categories of licensing, then the *finish* button will be enabled.